# AQL how to collect documents into arrays under their collection name?

Tags: arangodb, aql

In answer to previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48890455/7598113) was shown how to collect documents under their collection names but there was a clear constraint that query returns only one document for each collection.

@CoDEmanX asked what if the query returns many documents of the same collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will have to rework query to use aggregation:

```
FOR doc IN ANY "vertex/key" edge_collection
COLLECT collection = PARSE_IDENTIFIER(doc).collection INTO collected
RETURN MERGE({
    [collection]: collected[*].doc
})
```

- Group documents by their collection name `COLLECT collection = PARSE_IDENTIFIER(doc).collection INTO collected`
- Form document with collection name as property and array of collected documents as value `{ [collection]: collected[*].doc }`
- Merge results into single document

Comment: Why not use `"collection": PARSE_IDENTIFIER(v).collection` and `RETURN { [collection]: groups[*].i.item }`? Seems unnecessary to me create an array for the collection name only to get the sole element back from it.

Comment: Thanks, @CoDEmanX for noting unnecessary overcomplicating. I shall not post QAs after midnight while being totally exhausted. I’ve refactored answer to be as short and concise as possible.